# Can we use Google Maps JavaScript API v3 without Map purpose?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop an IOS app, that will use **Google Maps JavaScript API v3**,
but I dont want to display any information as **Map**.

If I just call a URL like -

***http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.81649,73.907807&destination=40.819585,-73.90177&sensor=false***

**Will it be allowed/restricted from Apple and Google?**

I just want to display the departure time, arrival time, transit information etc of stops/stations.

I dont want to display any information on **Map**, so can I use the above URL in my application?

Comment: You can called the Service for the `GeoCoding` but it's not ethic an violates the terms and used explicit say's that you cannot used this without the maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed! You may only use Google Maps Data if you are displaying a map that is publicly accessible. See [**section 9.1 of the TOS**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1) and **10.1.1 (g) ["No Use of Content without a Google Map.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)**":

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for ur reply, I need to think on it.

Comment: @Marcelo, I think "No Use of Content without a Google Map" says that content should not used without **Google Map**, But Deepu says 
**I dont want to display any information on Map**, i.e. he does not using any map to display info. and so I think this will not violate, isn't it?